# embed or encode static information in a C library?

Tags: c

This might be an odd ball question: I have a C library that needs to read in a relative large configuration file (10MB). The configuration files are static and preferably not to be read or viewed by casual library users. Suppose I don't care about the distribution size, what would be the best way to embed such info? I thought about encrypt it in some form and decrypt it on the fly, but then I have to dealt with clean up and doesn't seem more obfuscating. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

C does not, itself, provide any support for this at all. You can do it using third-party libraries or operating system features, but it's *highly* platform/environment-specific.

In Linux, with ELF executables, you can use the [ELF Resource Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfembed/) to embed resources.

In Windows, the [Windows Resource Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) embeds resources into PE executables. It is integrated very well with Visual Studio, but can be used separately.

Both of the above (and any embedded resource solution on any platform) rely on:

- Resource support in the executable format (ELF, PE, etc.)
- Library support to extract resources at runtime
- Compiler/linker support to embed resources at compile time